# Show/hide JQuery animation lag on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

Show/hide function are too slow on android.

html:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    Some text
</div>
<div class="button" id="addRes">show</div>
<div class="button" id="addResdd">hide</div>
```

js:

```
$("#addRes").click(function () {
    view();
});
$("#addResdd").click(function () {
    hide();
});

function view() {
     $('#mydiv').show('slow');   
}

function hide(){
    $('#mydiv').hide('slow');    
}
```

When I load my page with this code and try to show/hide text, animation is executed with delay and lags. Android 4.3, Samsung Galaxy S3.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try changing the .hide('slow') to 'fast'or .show('fast','swing')?

Comment: @NorthBlast yes, I tried, but I need slow animation.