# how to change hover effect speed in css3?

Tags: css

I have a list  which is hidden and on mouse hover it will be appeared. The problem is that it appears so fast.is these any way to reduce the speed of it appereance?

Comment: You could use JQuery to do that is really simple. You can refer to this post and check it out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701399/show-hide-jquery-animation-lag-on-android?noredirect=1#comment36421021_23701399 I hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In css we use transition property for this purpose... refer to this link.. [transition property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp)

Comment: may be you are not applying it properly... post your css code